# how to get page name from url (without extension)

Tags: php, get

How to get somtheng form the url page name?
Let's take as example: www.example.com/blabla/12345.php
I want to create an $id to take the value 12345, (without that .php) 
And why stackoverflow don't let me ask this simple question, and force me to add more text to accept my queston?.. I hope now it's better.

Comment: One more thing. what have you tried? :)

Comment: $id = $_GET['name']; ? :D

Comment: why are you making a file name like this `12345.php`? why not try like `filename.php?key=12345` and get the the id `$_GET['key']`

Answer (score 2):

```
php > var_dump(pathinfo('www.example.com/blabla/12345.php', PATHINFO_FILENAME));
string(5) "12345"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:

```
$uri = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$id= str_replace('.php','',end($uri));
```